# how to print a matrix with a negated row more efficiently

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, printf, pointer-arithmetic, function-definition

I wrote the following function:

```
void negate_row(const int n, const int r, int *a)
{
    if (r == 0)
    {
        printf("Matrix with negated row: ");
        printf("\n");
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            *(a + 3 * r + y) = *(a + 3 * r + y) *(-1);
            printf("%d ", *(a + 3 * r + y));
        }
        printf("\n");

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            *(a + 3 * r + y) = *(a + 3 * r + y) *(-1);
            printf("%d ", *(a + 3 * (r + 1) + y));
        }
        printf("\n");

        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
        {
            *(a + 3 * r + y) = *(a + 3 * r + y) *(-1);
            printf("%d ", *(a + 3 * (r + 2) + y));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

So basically what happens here is my function takes in a n X 3 matrix and negates a specific row using pointer arithmetic. I have been able to achieve that, I've also been able to figure out how to print that same matrix with the negated row. It's just the way I'm doing it is not efficient at all. I'd have to write an if statement for each row, ex if r == 0,1,2,3,4 etc... is there any way I can do this more efficiently?

Some clarifications: `const int n` decides the size of the matrix (n x 3), `const int r` decides what row is negated (`0` <= `r` < `n`).

Answer (score 0):

A second loop will help.  I generally find pointer code a bit harder to read.  Particularly with Matrix manipulation you might be better off using array syntax instead of pointer syntax.

```
for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(a + 3 * (r + x) + y));
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: he has `n` columns so it is `x < n`

Comment: The `x` loop should be the outer loop.

Comment: Yes.  You guys are correct.  I am simply addressing the question of how to reduce the duplicate code in his one loop.  That appears to be what the question is about.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and it does work. But there is a problem which is what I was facing and why I did the solution I did. Depending on which row is inputted to be negated, that row will print as the first row of the matrix. That's now how it's meant to be, the row that's chosen should remain in it's original spot. Ex if row 2 is chosen, it shouldn't become row 0, it should remain in its row 2 spot.

Answer (score 0):

Particular case (3 rows):

```cpp
int mul = 1, y = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    mul = x == r ? -1 : 1;
    y = (a + 3 * x);
    printf("%d ", (*y) * mul);
    printf("%d ", (*y + 1) * mul);
    printf("%d ", (*y + 2) * mul);
    printf("\n");
}
```

More generic (`m` rows):

```cpp
int mul = 1;
for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
    mul = x == r ? -1 : 1;
    for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
      printf("%d ", ((*(a + m * x + y)) * mul);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Note: In new compilers there is also no difference in speed between array or pointer syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that accepts a one-dimensional array (a row of your matrix) and then using this function you could in a loop output its all rows or output a selected row.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void negate_row( const int *a, size_t n, int width )
{
    if ( width < 1 ) width = 1;
    
    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%*d ", width, -*p );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 4 };
    int matrix[M][N] =
    {
        { 0,  1,  2,  4 },
        { 5,  6,  7,  8 },
        { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
    };
    
    for ( int ( *p )[N] = matrix; p != matrix + M; ++p )
    {
        negate_row( *p, N, 3 );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
  0  -1  -2  -4 
 -5  -6  -7  -8 
 -9 -10 -11 -12
```

As you showed a code where you are using pointers tp output elements of an array then in this demonstrative program I am also using pointers everywhere to access elements of an array.

The third parameter of the function specifies the width of the field for an outputted value.

To output the matrix in the reversed order of rows you can use the loop shown in the program blow.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void negate_row( const int *a, size_t n, int width )
{
    if ( width < 1 ) width = 1;
    
    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%*d ", width, -*p );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { M = 3, N = 4 };
    int matrix[M][N] =
    {
        { 0,  1,  2,  4 },
        { 5,  6,  7,  8 },
        { 9, 10, 11, 12 }
    };
    
    for ( int ( *p )[N] = matrix + M; p != matrix;  )
    {
        negate_row( *--p, N, 3 );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
 -9 -10 -11 -12 
 -5  -6  -7  -8 
  0  -1  -2  -4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generalize the function easily: as long as the row is within the matrix, your code works for any row. Also note that it is better to use a separate function to print the matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void negate_row(const int n, const int r, int *a) {
    if (r >= 0 && r < n) {
        // negate row r
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            *(a + 3 * r + col) *= -1;
        }
    }
}

void print_matrix(const int n, int *a, const char *title) {
    if (title) {
        printf("%s:\n", title);
    }
    for (int row = 0; row < n; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            printf("%d ", *(a + 3 * row + col));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    int matrix[5 * 3] = {
        0, 1, 2,
        3, 4, 5,
        6, 7, 8,
        9, 10, 11,
        12, 13, 14,
    };
    print_matrix(5, matrix, "Matrix");
    negate_row(5, 0, matrix);
    print_matrix(5, matrix, "Matrix with negated row");
    negate_row(5, 3, matrix);
    print_matrix(5, matrix, "Matrix with two negated rows");
    negate_row(5, 0, matrix);
    negate_row(5, 3, matrix);
    print_matrix(5, matrix, "Matrix back to origin");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Matrix:
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11
12 13 14

Matrix with negated row:
0 -1 -2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11
12 13 14

Matrix with two negated rows:
0 -1 -2
3 4 5
6 7 8
-9 -10 -11
12 13 14

Matrix back to origin:
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9 10 11
12 13 14
```